# How to set the Xfermode in Paint object in Harmony OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

How can we replicate the Android behaviour of this code snippet from [SharpView](https://github.com/zengzhaoxing/SharpView/blob/257cda0e24e43705ec2f48b2cb52f2fd3c447da3/sharpview/src/main/java/com/zhaoxing/view/sharpview/SharpImageView.java#L55) library in Harmony OS?

```
private PorterDuffXfermode mPorterDuffXfermode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

mPaint.setXfermode(mPorterDuffXfermode);
mOutCanvas.drawBitmap(mSoftBitmap.get(), rect, rect, mPaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

**BlendMode** API is the Harmony alternative for **PorterDuffXfermode**.

you can achieve same functionality using,

```java
mPaint.setBlendMode(BlendMode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `setBlendMode` method.

[image]

For more details, you can check [this Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/paint-0000001054358720).